# Spring security - Secure a request by validating principle against @RequestParam parameter?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-el

I work with Restful API (with many urls) using Spring 3.1.2, and want to apply security filters per request that uses both data from the authenticated user "principal" and the data sent by the request.

**example:**

validate accountId from request url:

`http://www.foo.com/accountRecords?accountId=23`

with principal data `principal.accountId = 23`.

I know this can be done from within the @requestMapping methods, but want to do it **outside** the actual method, so it will be maintainable and configurable without interfering the business logic.

But I didn't find any advice\sample about it..

I believe it should look something like:
`@PreAuthorize("principal.accountId == requestParam.accountId")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking for filters to filter the request and response. In Spring, you can use `interceptors` for this purpose.

```
public class MyInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter {
    @Override
    public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) throws Exception {
        HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);
        String requestParam = request.getParameter("your request param");
    }
}
```

Finally, you need to configure these interceptors in your context.xml file:

```
<mvc:interceptors>
        <mvc:interceptor>
            <mvc:mapping path="/**"/>
            <bean class="com.example.MyInterceptor" />
        </mvc:interceptor>                
    </mvc:interceptors>
```

Comment: Thanks, I believe interceptors are too high level for me, in the Spring documentation interceptors are filtering by a regular expression and permissions, but has no access to the request parameters.

If you could provide a sample code I would appreciate it.

Comment: look at the edited answer for example. See you can use the request parameters.

Comment: I see. good example :)
Do you know how can I access the security principal (username and account for instance) from MyInterceptor?